# Doctrine2 + Symfony2: Como trazer mais de uma entidade no queryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony-2, doctrine-2

Olá.

Estou com a seguinte dúvida.

Estou fazendo um select em várias tabelas diferentes, quero trazer algumas delas. Mas de todo jeito que eu tento, ou retorna apenas a principal ou da um erro.

Pode me ajudar?

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select( ['c as customer','b as bankAccount']  )
        ->from('MyBundle:BankAccount', 'b')
        ->join('b.customer', 'c')
        ->join('c.prepaidCards', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('c.addresses', 'a', Join::WITH, 'a.type = :address_type')
        ->leftJoin('a.city', 'ci')
        ->leftJoin('a.state', 's')
        ->leftJoin('c.company', 'co')
        ->where('b.accountType = :account_type')
        ->andWhere('b.isActive = 1')
        ->andWhere('p.status = :card_status')
        ->andWhere('p.shippingType ' . (is_null($shippingType) ? 'IS NULL' : '= :shipping_type'))
        ->andWhere('c.status IN (:customer_status)')
        ->setParameter('account_type', BankAccount::ACCOUNT_TYPE_CARD)
        ->setParameter('card_status', PrepaidCard::CARD_STATUS_ASSIGNED)
        ->setParameter('address_type', Address::TYPE_SHIPPING);
    if (!is_null($shippingType)) {
        $qb->setParameter('shipping_type', $shippingType);
    }
    $result = $qb->setParameter('customer_status', [Customer::STATUS_ACCEPTED, Customer::STATUS_ACTIVATED])
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Já tentei o trecho:

```
->select( ['c as customer','b as bankAccount']  )
```

Como:

```
->select( 'c as customer, b as bankAccount'  )

->select( ['c','b']  )

->select( 'c','b'  )
```

E alguns outros que não me recordo no momento.

Preciso trazer 'c', 'b', 'p', 'a', 'ci', 's'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta fazer assim:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('b, c, p, a, ci, s')
    ->from('MyBundle:BankAccount', 'b')
    ->join('b.customer', 'c')
    ->join('c.prepaidCards', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('c.addresses', 'a', Join::WITH, 'a.type = :address_type')
    ->leftJoin('a.city', 'ci')
    ->leftJoin('a.state', 's')
    ->leftJoin('c.company', 'co')
    ->where('b.accountType = :account_type')
    ->andWhere('b.isActive = 1')
    ->andWhere('p.status = :card_status')
    ->andWhere('p.shippingType ' . (is_null($shippingType) ? 'IS NULL' : '= :shipping_type'))
    ->andWhere('c.status IN (:customer_status)')
    ->setParameter('account_type', BankAccount::ACCOUNT_TYPE_CARD)
    ->setParameter('card_status', PrepaidCard::CARD_STATUS_ASSIGNED)
    ->setParameter('address_type', Address::TYPE_SHIPPING);
if (!is_null($shippingType)) {
    $qb->setParameter('shipping_type', $shippingType);
}
$result = $qb
    ->setParameter('customer_status', [Customer::STATUS_ACCEPTED, Customer::STATUS_ACTIVATED])
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: Apenas retorna o BankAccount:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(MyBundle\Entity\BankAccount)[5575]

Comment: É a partir desse objeto que você irá acessar os outros objetos. O DQL retorna apenas o objeto principal (da cláusula `FROM`). O recurso de separar os objetos por vírgula existe para o Doctrine trazer todos os objetos relacionados de uma vez só, e não trazê-los um por um quando você iterar por um determinado atributo do objeto principal.

Comment: Ok, se eu quiser trazer os prepaidCards eu teria que acessar $bank->getCustomer()->getPrepaidCards(); ele retornaria todos do cliente. Eu teria que pegar o id do cartao e depois trazer via getRepository? Tem algum meio mais fácil?

Comment: Não é necessário usar o repositório de cartões para trazê-los um a um se eles já vêm na consulta principal. Se você está dando um `join` em `prepaidCards`, isso traduzirá em um `INNER JOIN` quando a query efetivamente rodar no banco. Ou seja, os cartões já serão trazidos juntos com o resultset principal. Você pode fazer o seguinte para ler os cartões da consulta: `foreach ($bankAccount->getCustomer()->getPrepaidCards() as $prepaidCard()) { echo $prepaidCard->getId(); }`.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado. Acho q eu estava fazendo algo errado antes, porque agora deu certo. Estava retornando todos os endereços do customer, agora esta trazendo somente o correto.